# Bootstrap4 Datetimepicker not working in rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the datetimepicker function from bootstrap4, I'm using this gem [datetimepicker](https://github.com/Bialogs/bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails).
this is my gemfile(part of it)

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'responders'
gem 'bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails'
gem 'mini_racer'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
```

this is the simple html.erb file

```
<h1>Bets#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/bets/show.html.erb</p>
<div class="datetimepicker1">
  <input name="prova" data-format="dd/MM/yy hh:mm"/>
</div>
```

and this is the coffee file

```
$(".datetimepicker1").datetimepicker
```

What I'm missing? It should work like this

[EDIT] I also added the require in application.js and import in application.scss

Comment: be sure that you are initializing it after the element exist in the dom, so call your js at the end of the html, or call it inside a `$(document).ready`

Comment: I'm using turbolink, so the coffee file already contains the "$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` . Then datepicker will be available in your app.

- To require all jQuery UI modules, add the following to your application.js

`//= require jquery-ui`

- add the jQuery UI CSS to your application.css

  `/*
  *= require jquery-ui
  */`
- Jquery

  `$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });`

Comment: I need a datetimepicker with time, I don't know if jquey ui has it

Comment: please try with gem 'rails-assets-datetimepicker'